# git merge, why no Fast-forward every time ?

Tags: git, git-merge, fast-forward

I make a branch (b1) from develop branch

```
git checkout -b b1
```

and make some commmits over `b1`

at same time, make some commits over `develop`, when I try merge the commit of develop over b1

```
git merge develop
```

the merge editor is open, and a no Fast-forward is make

```
d25ef61 Merge branch 'develop' into b1
```

why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast-forward merge happens when there are no new commits on the base branch, so that the commits you're merging can be appended directly.

Since you want to merge two different subtrees of commits together, you need a merge commit.

Alternatively, you can use `git rebase` to reproduce the new commits onto the base branch.
This will create a separate copy of each commit; use with caution.

Comment: "so that the commits you're merging can be appended directly." --- actually nothing is being added. Only a pointer is moved.